# Howto use a Timer in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I tried to find out how to use a Timer in C# but I never really understood any of the tutorials.
I want to get a loop that waits a second then does something (Not a Thread.Delay. Something that can run simultaneously while other things happen). If someone could kindly tell me how to write the code or write me a sample that a beginner that can understand I'd be greatly appreciative.

```
    public partial class Char1 : Form
{
    private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
    public static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Mainprog.count += 1;
    }
    public Char1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            aTimer.Interval = 2000;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
            aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to make it call the event every 2 seconds but it crashes. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: C# I forgot to add it, my bad

Comment: What platform: asp.net, winforms, ...

Comment: I would suggest looking at the documentation for `Timer`, `Thread` and `ThreadPool`. There are examples of how to use those classes. When you have tried and failed, post the code that does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you shouldn't enable the timer in a while loop and you should definitely not add eventlistners in a while loop since that's the reason why your program is crashing, also timer.start() is what i use, i'm not familiar with timer.enable try it like this:

```
public partial class Char1 : Form
{
    private System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

    public static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Mainprog.count += 1;
    }
    public Char1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        aTimer = new Timer();
        aTimer.Interval = 2000;
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            aTimer.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            aTimer.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

so instantiate your timer in the constructor and also define your interval there unless you want to change your interval when the checkbox is checked or unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way nowadays:

```
while(true) {
    await Task.Delay (1000);
    DoSomething ();
}
```

Comment: the loop will run on the current thread, but won't prevent other operation to run. Read about TPL and async/await in .NET 4.5

Comment: doesn't `await` need to be used in an `async` method?

Comment: The method needs to be tagged with `async` indeed. But that's it. You can then use it almost like an ordinary one.

Answer (score 1):

Your (recently added) code

```
    while (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        aTimer.Interval = 2000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
    }
```

contains some problems:

- when the checkbox is checked, you will get into an infinite loop (you don't have time to uncheck the box)
- in that loop you keep adding (`+=`) new eventhandlers to the timer, so that if it gets to firing, you fire off thousands of `OnTimedEvent` calls.

Solution: replace the `while` with an `if` and make sure that you add that OnTimedEvent just once, by moving that line to the construction of the form.

Answer (score 0):

You could use TimerCallback and timer to run a method in another thread like this:

```
TimerCallback tCb = Method;

        Timer t = new Timer(tCb, null, 1000, 1000);         
    }

    private void Method(object sender)
    {       
       //your
    }
```

It will run Method every second (period) after waiting one second (dueTime).